# Can a function smash through tryCatch and friends?

Tags: r, error-handling

I know how to raise an error:

```
check_negative <- function(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    stop("No way can x be positive.")
  }
  x
}

check_negative(5)
#> Error in check_negative(5) : No way can x be positive.
```

Since the purpose of `tryCatch` is to handle such errors, but `tryCatch` is not strictly reserved, I wondered if there is a way to always raise an error when `check_negative(5)` occurs, even if it's wrapped in `tryCatch`.

My first approach works reasonably well, but needs to run at least once and doesn't fix `tryCatch` on exit. I tried putting the `tryCatch` 'repair' before the error within `on.exit`, but that resulted in the error not being raised.

(Naturally, the following function does some damage to your R session, so run with care and don't run in a session you want preserved.)

```
check_negative <- function(x) {
  unlockBinding("tryCatch", baseenv())
  assign("tryCatch", 
         local({
           function(expr, ..., finally) {
             expr
           }
         }), 
         pos = baseenv())

  if (x > 0) {
    stop("No way can x be positive.")
  }
  # Attempt to repair tryCatch
  unlockBinding("tryCatch", baseenv())
  assign("tryCatch", 
         function (expr, ..., finally) 
         {
           tryCatchList <- function(expr, names, parentenv, handlers) {
             nh <- length(names)
             if (nh > 1L) 
               tryCatchOne(tryCatchList(expr, names[-nh], parentenv, 
                                        handlers[-nh]), names[nh], parentenv, handlers[[nh]])
             else if (nh == 1L) 
               tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
             else expr
           }
           tryCatchOne <- function(expr, name, parentenv, handler) {
             doTryCatch <- function(expr, name, parentenv, handler) {
               .Internal(.addCondHands(name, list(handler), parentenv, 
                                       environment(), FALSE))
               expr
             }
             value <- doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
             if (is.null(value[[1L]])) {
               msg <- .Internal(geterrmessage())
               call <- value[[2L]]
               cond <- simpleError(msg, call)
             }
             else cond <- value[[1L]]
             value[[3L]](cond)
           }
           if (!missing(finally)) 
             on.exit(finally)
           handlers <- list(...)
           classes <- names(handlers)
           parentenv <- parent.frame()
           if (length(classes) != length(handlers)) 
             stop("bad handler specification")
           tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
         }, 
         pos = baseenv())
}

tryCatch(check_negative(5), error = function(e) NULL)
#> NULL
tryCatch(check_negative(5), error = function(e) NULL)
#> Error in check_negative(5) : No way can x be positive.
```

My main motivation behind this question is curiosity; I don't intend to do this. But I do want to know whether something like this is possible or whether is is possible to write a function where an unsuspicious yet determined user would be unable to avoid an error.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `stop` asynchronously. This requires the `later` package.

```
check_negative <- function(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    later::later(function(...) stop('No way can x be positive.'))
    stop("No way can x be positive.")
  }
  x
}
tryCatch(check_negative(5), error = function(e) NULL)
#> NULL
#> Error in tryCatch(evalq(sys.calls(), <environment>), error = function (x)  : 
#>   Evaluation error: No way can x be positive..
```